# Cannot cast Android screen to Philips TV

Tags: android-tv, chromecast

I have a Philips 50PFK6550/12 TV, and a Nexus 5X running Marshmallow.
When I try to cast the screen of my Nexus to the TV using the Cast button in the notifications menu, the cast app crashes on my TV:

> Unfortunately, Chromecast Android Shell has stopped.

I can then report this error. If I view the stack trace, it says:

```
java.lang.securityException: Cast mirroring is not enabled.
```

Trying to cast a tab from Google Chrome on my desktop gives the same error.

Is there some way I can make this work, or is this something Google/Philips needs to fix?

Comment: Settings > Display > cast > 3 dots on the top right > Enable wireless display. Is that On?

Comment: Thanks! I don't have the 'Enable wireless display' option there, only 'Help & feedback'. I do see the TV, but connecting makes the app on the TV crash.

Comment: Oh so you mean to say the Chromecast crashed. Sorry. I though something derped on the phone. Worth resetting the chromecast, though. Is it updated to the latest version?

Comment: Yeah well, the TV runs Android, and has 'native' chromecast support. That crashes. I have tried to reinstall the cast app and do a factory reset of the TV.

Comment: Would this help? [Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/Chromecast/comments/3outqd/cast_feature_not_working_on_philips_tv/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. I'm starting to think the TV is just buggy. It won't even accept signals from my remote until I reboot it..

Comment: Let's try a full reset and see if that fixes anything. :)

Comment: Yes, I'll try that again. If that doesn't help I'll contact Philips :)

Comment: Ah, the reviews on the [Google Cast Receiver app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.mediashell) show I'm not the only one with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bought a separate Chromecast. This works fine.